# When user removes app shortcut how to change shared preference

Tags: java, android

Using this i am creating app shortcut, but when user removes it from home screen then how to check

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(context, Doctor.class);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Constants.SEARCH_QUERY_HINT, getResources().getString(R.string.Search_By_name_speciality));
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Doctor");
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.doctor));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Comment: I guess a better question why should you need to know that a user has removed your app shortcut?

Comment: actually i am saving value in shared preferences to avoid duplication of shortcut, so when user removes the app shortcut i want to change the preference value

Comment: I guess if a user chooses to duplicate your shortcut, that would be the user's preference. Why should that matter to your app? What does your preference mean? I guess in short.. Why do you need to know it was removed? Perhaps code it in a way where it doesn't matter - ultimately drilling down on the question of why and whether or not what you're asking is necessary in the first place.

Comment: but i don't wanted user to create duplicate shortcut

Comment: if you have seen whats app "add chat shortcut", i want same as that. and it do not create duplicate of chat shortcut